# GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails for Paypal standard

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring

I am using paypal standard in my website and we are using recurring payment method for that,and i done it successfully. but now i wanting to know all the details of that recurring payment profile. i had googling for that and i got `"GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails"` API for get profile details.but as i know its working with `PAYPAL PRO` only.

Is anybody having solution the same for `PAYPAL STANDARD`..? i m stuck on that task from many days.please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails works for both Express Checkout as well as Website Payments Pro recurring payment profiles.

If you use Standard, you may or may not be able to use this API. Give it a shot I'd say!